# Auto-generated data layer vs. manully-written data layer in asp.net - which one is better?

Tags: asp.net, code-generation

I'm just wondering about an auto-generated data layer vs. a manually-coded data layer. Which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

That is such an open ended question - neither is better, it all depends on your project.

If i'm only coding against a single database then i like to hand code my data layer, it really doesn't take long and i'm in full control of what i get. If i'm coding against more than one database then i would consider using a code generator to generate the basic classes and then extend them if i need to, code generators tend to spit out partial classes which is how you extend them.

Comment: Are you talking about one database table or one physical database? One table is like five queries (create, read by ID, update, delete and list all) where as one database could be thousands of similar queries.